# Cannot get the my location dot for Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Currently, I am not able to get my location in the app I am developing.

Basically, in the documentation for Google Maps iOS SDK, Google mentions that you can:

> enable the blue "My Location" dot and compass direction by setting
>   myLocationEnabled on GMSMapView
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/map#my_location

However, when I do that, the dot does not appear in my view.

Here's my setup, I have a view controller that contains a view. This view contains three things, two buttons and a map view:

[image]

I have linked my mapView with GMSMapView and I can see the map without any problems.

Now, what I would want, is to be located.

I tried two things. First, using a custom, draft button (the i for information), I tried to manually set the location to the mapView but this wasn't working even though the locationServicesEnabled method returned YES.

Then, I tried using GoogleMaps's dot but this isn't working either.

Here's my code:

**StudyDisplayViewController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"


@interface StudyDisplayViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

}

@property (strong, readwrite) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**StudyDisplayViewController.m**

```
#import "StudyDisplayViewController.h"

@interface StudyDisplayViewController ()
- (IBAction)closeStudyDisplay:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)locateMe:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation StudyDisplayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        NSLog(@"Starting the location service");
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            NSLog(@"all good");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Damn son");
        }
    }

    self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;       

    self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;    
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    NSLog(@"Getting Location");
}


/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (IBAction)closeStudyDisplay:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)locateMe:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"User's location: %@", self.mapView.myLocation);

}
```

I am using Xcode 6.3.2 and iOS 8.3.

Comment: `GMSMapView *mapView_;` Have you bind any outlet, because right now it seems that mapView_ will be Nil.

Comment: Yes I have, sorry this part was a try and error on my side I'll adjust it

Comment: Then please checkout my Answer below if it helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check out following things are there or not.

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    locationManager.delegate= self;
    if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    _mapView.myLocationEnabled =  YES;
    _mapView.settings.myLocationButton =  YES;
```

If Everything is there and if you are testing on Simulator then try to change the location in Simulator from debug Tab, e.g. change It to Free car run of any of them.

Also, check if you have added Description in PLIST for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: I'm testing on my iPhone, I'll try your solution and I'll let you know, thanks for that

Comment: Ok fine, I think there might be issue due to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` in your case.

Comment: You do not have to use the CLLocationManager to actually find your current location.  Google Maps does that for you. So unless you actually need to retrieve the GPS coordinates of your current location, all you need do is 1. Create a new CLLocationManager. 2. Use the location Manager to requestWhenInUseAuthorization.  This should be all you need to do to show the blue dot (assuming you have set you mapView.myLocationEnabled, mapView.settings.myLocationButton = truel